# Display JSON Objects as options in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-select

I have a simple HTML page in which I would like to read objects from a JSON file and show them as options in a dropdown using JavaScript. HTML and JSON are as below :

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <select id="myid">MyList</select>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JSON**

```
[{"Mode":"CARD"},
{"Mode":"CASH"},
{"Mode":"CHEQUE"}];
```

Any help w.r.t. the JavaScript is much appreciated!

Comment: can you use jquery too?

Comment: This question shows no effect and is too broad as it currently stands. You should start with an introductory JavaScript tutorial or hire a freelancer. Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @Harry thank you for that. I am new to StackOverflow too, will take care and not use "fluff" anymore! Cheers! :)

Comment: @mike I can use JQuery too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working and Tested code**, for reading the external local JSON file (data.json) using javascript, first create your data.json file with below data:

```
data = '[{"Mode":"CARD"}, {"Mode":"CASH"}, {"Mode":"CHEQUE"}]';
```

Mention the path of the JSON file in the script tag

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
    <script>
        function addOptions(){
            var jsonArray = JSON.parse(data);
            var select = document.getElementById('dd');
            var option;
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
              option = document.createElement('option');
              option.text = jsonArray[i]["Mode"];
              select.add(option);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <body onload="addOptions();">
        <select id="dd"></select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why downvote... have courtesy to explain it too.

Comment: The question is asking how to load in data from a JSON file. You're hard coded the data in to the JavaScript instead of using JSON. You're also using jQuery despite [the `javascript` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) saying: *Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected*

Comment: *first create your data.json file with below data *: `data = '[{"Mode":"CARD"}, {"Mode":"CASH"}, {"Mode":"CHEQUE"}]';` that's JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks for let me know this. Actually I believe question has been changed many time as initially read from was not mentioned or may be missed it. Now I have modified it.

Comment: The edit history of the question shows that the original version of the question said "read objects from a JSON file". The most recent edit of your answer shows you loading data from a JavaScript file (albeit one with a .json file extension), not a JSON file.

Comment: Yes, I can `parse` it and get a `JSON` out of it? I believe it is valid JSON

Comment: Having a JavaScript variable with JSON embedded in it is not the same thing as loading a JSON file.

Comment: Thanks @mike! your solution is absolutely amazing and working! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @TheLuminor - Glad to help you. You might forgot to do upvote ;) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you had a server resource that returned the following.
**/myjson**

```
[
    {
        "Mode": "CARD"
    },
    {
        "Mode": "CASH"
    },
    {
        "Mode": "CHEQUE"
    }
]
```

Then create the `<option>` elements using JavaScript.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/myjson',
    type:'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        $.each(json, function(i, value) {
            $('#myid').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value.Mode));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I'd prefer not to use ajax and go ahead with what @mike suggested! Thank you though! :)